# Mutually exclusive events in prolog

Tags: prolog, probability

I want to define events in prolog where if one happens the other cannot.

For example I have 5 boxes of different sizes, say 50,50,50,80,90 squared cm, and 4 storage spaces and if I put a box in one storage space I want it not to able to be stored twice. Furthermore, I want to overall size stored to be 230. So in effect, I want to calculate all possible scenarios where that can happen and which box is in which storage space.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: You want to calculate all the possible scenerios where the stored size is less than 230?

Comment: Where it is exactly 230.

Answer (score 1):

I would model this with a term and a storage routine, something like this:

```
% this is a start state
start(storage(empty, empty, empty, empty)).
```

This gives you 4 storage spaces. Now you need a rule for inserting into them.

```
store(BoxSize, storage(empty, S2, S3, S4), storage(BoxSize, S2, S3, S4)).
store(BoxSize, storage(S1, empty, S3, S4), storage(S1, BoxSize, S3, S4)).
store(BoxSize, storage(S1, S2, empty, S4), storage(S1, S2, BoxSize, S4)).
store(BoxSize, storage(S1, S2, S3, empty), storage(S1, S2, S3, BoxSize)).
```

This defines `store/3`, which takes a new box (represented by its size) and your structure of 4 storage spaces, and it places that box in the next empty bin in your storage spaces.

Now you can sum up how much space you're using pretty easily:

```
total(storage(S1, S2, S3, S4), Total) :-
    findall(N, (member(N, [S1, S2, S3, S4]), number(N)), Sizes),
    sumlist(Sizes, Total).
```

It's tempting to write `Total is S1+S2+S3+S4` but that will fail if any bin is empty.

This is how you use what we've built here so far:

```
?- start(Store), store(40, Store, NewStore), 
   store(50, NewStore, NewerStore), total(NewerStore, Total).
Store = storage(empty, empty, empty, empty),
NewStore = storage(40, empty, empty, empty),
NewerStore = storage(40, 50, empty, empty),
Total = 90 ;
Store = storage(empty, empty, empty, empty),
NewStore = storage(40, empty, empty, empty),
NewerStore = storage(40, empty, 50, empty),
Total = 90 ;
```

As you can see, we're able to add things to the store, and it is giving us alternative solutions by moving the bins around in the different slots. Threading the state around manually isn't a lot of fun; you would probably write this as a fold or use `phrase/3` to thread the state so that you don't need to keep making intermediate states.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with respect to your list of five items. So you will have to probably take it from here to figure out how you want to insert them and meet your constraints. I'd guess you want to do something with `select/3` where you put them in the bins, get the size, and forget about whatever is left over.

Comment: The `findall/3` construct could be replaced by `include(number, [S1, S2, S3, S4], Sizes)` if your Prolog has `include/3` with this filtering semantics.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Yes, that is a definite improvement.

Comment: When you insert into the storage space are you assuming that all spaces are filled except the last one?

Comment: @System on the contrary, I assume nothing. Read the code! I only fill a slot if the current content of that slot is the atom `empty`.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of this question is that you are looking for all permutations of elements from the list `[50, 50, 50, 80, 90]` of size at most 4 and sum at most 230. The solution here is deliberately primitive, not exploiting any symmetries, not even the equality of the multiple occurrences of the number 50.

So, let's start with a predicate that describes such permutations of elements of a list with a bounded size. It's easiest to use a DCG to do define this:

```
permuted_sublist(List, MaxLength, PermutedSublist) :-
    phrase(permuted_sublist(List, MaxLength), PermutedSublist).

permuted_sublist(_List, _N) -->
    [].
permuted_sublist(List, N) -->
    { N > 0 },
    { select(Element, List, List1) },
    [Element],
    { N1 is N - 1 },
    permuted_sublist(List1, N1).
```

One subtlety is that the head of the first clause matches *any* length, not just 0. If we put `0` for `_N`, this grammar would describe sublists of length *exactly* the number given, but we also want to allow shorter ones.

Test:

```
?- permuted_sublist([a, b, c, d, e], 2, Selection).
Selection = [] ;
Selection = [a] ;
Selection = [a, b] ;
Selection = [a, c] ;
Selection = [a, d] ;
Selection = [a, e] ;
Selection = [b] ;
Selection = [b, a] ;
Selection = [b, c] ;
Selection = [b, d] ;
Selection = [b, e] ;
Selection = [c] ;  % etc
```

Given this, we just need to add the constraint on the sum:

```
placement(Sizes, Selection, Sum) :-
    permuted_sublist(Sizes, 4, Selection),
    sumlist(Selection, Sum),
    Sum =< 230.
```

And this behaves as follows:

```
?- placement([50, 50, 50, 80, 90], Placement, Sum).
Placement = [],
Sum = 0 ;
Placement = [50],
Sum = 50 ;
Placement = [50, 50],
Sum = 100 ;
Placement = [50, 50, 50],
Sum = 150 ;
Placement = [50, 50, 50, 80],
Sum = 230 ;
Placement = [50, 50, 80],
Sum = 180 ;
Placement = [50, 50, 80, 50],
Sum = 230 ;  % etc
```

Again, there are redundancies in this that could be reduced by replacing the `select/3` goal with `append(_Prefix, [Element|List1], List)`.